# Wordpress custom post_type archive url and default query

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes, custom-post-type

I'm now using wordpress 4.2, and developing themes on it for my own site.

I defined many custom post types in my theme, and I'm now finding a way to make some archive pages for them.

---

For example, I have a post_type called `shop`, and have a taxonomy named `region` assigned to it.

I to created a template file: `category-region.php`

Then I visit the permalink of this template: `http://example.com/category/region/`, this template was matched, and init the query with all assigned shops, then display them.

But now I want to make a page with all posts of shop, no matter which region they are assigned.

How should I name the template file and what about the permalink?

---

I checked for the template hierarchy and have found the below diagram.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

[image]

It seems `archive-$post_type.php` is what I wanted.

But what about the permalink that is pointing to this template?

Comment: Is region a custom taxonomy or just a category term? `category-region.php` should be the template file for the `region` category.

Comment: @mtinsley yes, taxonomy.

Comment: See this issue: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_query-with-custom-post_type-and-global-category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rewrite` parameter in the arguments you pass to `register_post_type` determines the permalink for your custom post type archive.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Looking at the example in the documentation:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
);

register_post_type( 'book', $args );
```

You can see that the rewrite slug for the book CPT is `book`, so the URL to the book archive would be `example.com/book/`.

In your case, if you set your rewrite slug to `shop` (or if you didn't set a rewrite slug, in which case it would default to your CPT slug), the URL that would correspond to your `archive-shop.php` template would be `example.com/shop/`.

*Note that this assumes you are using permalinks, if you are not using permalinks the shop post type archive is located at `example.com/?post_type=shop`. If you are using permalink, make sure you refresh them after setting up your CPT by visiting the `Settings > Permalinks` page.*

Comment: Not exactly. This setting did not match my want. And I finally found the result is `/?post_type=shop`. You solution did not point this out, but shows useful information, thank you!

Comment: My solution was assuming you were using permalinks. When using permalinks, `example.com/shop/` is mapped to `example.com/?post_type=shop`

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you. I've tried but failed. And now I found it was because I forgot to refresh the `.htaccess` file. Your solution is great perfect!